# Aggregate query across two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working in BigQuery. I've got two tables:

```
TABLE: orgs
code: STRING
group: STRING

TABLE: org_employees
code: STRING
employee_count: INTEGER
```

The `code` in each table is effectively a foreign key. I want to get all unique `group`s, with a count of the orgs in them, and (this is the tricky bit) a count of how many of of those orgs only have a single employee. Data that looks like this:

```
group,orgs,single_handed_orgs
00Q,23,12
00K,15,7
```

I know how to do the first bit, get the unique `group`s and count of associated orgs from the `orgs` table:

```
SELECT
  count(code), group
FROM
  [orgs]
GROUP BY group
```

And, I know how to get the count of single-handed orgs from the practice table:

```
SELECT
  code,
  (employee_count==1) AS is_single_handed
FROM
  [org_employees]
```

But I'm not sure how to glue them together. Can anyone help?

Comment: In orgs table who is primary key?

Comment: In org_employees you have for each code a number of associated employees?

Comment: You have writeen code is a foreign key. What's the name of table where code is primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> for BigQuery: legacy SQL

```
SELECT
  [group], 
  COUNT(o.code) as orgs, 
  SUM(employee_count = 1) as single_handed_orgs
FROM [orgs] AS o
LEFT JOIN [org_employees] AS e
ON e.code  = o.code
GROUP BY [group]
```

using LEFT JOIN in case if some codes are missing in org_employees tables

> for BigQuery: standard SQL

```
SELECT
  grp, 
  COUNT(o.code) AS orgs , 
  SUM(CASE employee_count WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS single_handed_orgs
FROM orgs AS o
LEFT JOIN org_employees AS e
ON e.code  = o.code
GROUP BY grp
```

Note use of `grp` vs `group` - looks like standard sql does like use of [Reserved Keywords](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/lexical#reserved-keywords) even if i put backticks around

> Confirmed:

you can use keyword with backticks around

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - can you give repro for reserved keywords. I.e., the following query which backticks `group` works fine: select `group` from (select 1 as `group`) group by `group`

Comment: somehow it didnt worked for me when i answered the question. will check again

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky - i am confirnming that at a time when i answered the question - the test query failed with "Unrecognized token SetOperation (error code: invalidQuery)" and I attributed this (most likely wrongly) to use of reserved keyword because as soon as I changed field name error disappeared. Right now - exactly same query works w/o error. I will send you more details via email

Comment: I also noted that you escaped table name with [ ] - this won't work in standard SQL, either drop [ ] completely or use backticks instead if table name has special characters.

Comment: absolutelly. you are right . that part was just copy-paste from question :o) thank you for pointing.

Comment: sent repro info via email

Comment: it looks like that error was while i was in legacy mode while i thought i was in standard more. sorry for confusion. think answer still make sense :o)

Answer (score 0):

You could join the two tables to get the groups that have just one employee. Then you wrap this in a sub query and you count the groups that you have.

I'm using a COUNT DISTINCT and GROUP BY because I don't know how your data is structured. Is there only a single line per group or multiple?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT group)
FROM (
    SELECT
        group
    FROM
        orgs AS o INNER JOIN org_employees AS e ON o.code = e.code
    WHERE
        employee_count = 1
    GROUP BY
        group
    )
```