# How to write a LEFT JOIN in BigQuery's Standard SQL?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

We have a query that works in BigQuery's Legacy SQL. How do we write it in Standard SQL so it works?

```
SELECT Hour, Average, L.Key AS Key FROM
(SELECT 1 AS Key, * 
FROM test.table_L AS L)
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT 1 AS Key, Avg(Total) AS Average 
FROM test.table_R) AS R 
ON L.Key = R.Key ORDER BY Hour ASC
```

Currently the error it gives is:

```
Equality is not defined for arguments of type ARRAY<INT64> at [4:74]
```

BigQuery has two modes for queries: Legacy SQL and Standard SQL. We have looked at the [BigQuery Standard SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join_types) and also see just [one SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931291/aggregate-query-across-two-tables-in-sql/36939493#36939493) on Standard SQL joins in BigQuery - but so far, it is unclear to us what the key change needed might be.

Table_L looks like this:

```
Row    Hour
 1      A
 2      B
 3      C
```

Table_R looks like this:

```
Row    Value
 1      10
 2      20
 3      30
```

Results Desired:

```
Row  Hour  Average(OfR)  Key
 1     A      20          1
 2     B      20          1 
 3     C      20          1
```

How do we rewrite this BigQuery Legacy SQL query to work in Standard SQL?

Comment: What do you want this query to do?  Unless `key` is a column in `table_L` this shouldn't work in either version.

Comment: show the query that works for you in Legacy SQL, so we will be able to help you with working version in Standard SQL

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant The query that works in Legacy SQL listed is already shown. That's the one that gives the error when used in Standard SQL which is shown as well.

Comment: query in your question makes no much sense so it is hard to help w/o understanding what it is that you are trying to do. I suggest you to explain what exactly you do with example of input data and expected output

Comment: @GordonLinoff The query is adding the average of the table on the "right" to every row of the "left" table. It a way of doing a cross join. It works fine on BigQuery. Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Example tables added.

Comment: @Praxiteles . . . Because the `ON` condition has `l.key` in it.  Unless that is a column in the table, then you'll get an error.  And, you already have two columns with `key` in the `select`, which is awkward at the very least.

Comment: @Praxiteles - key field is not in any of your table  - what is the meaning/logic behind "key" field?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant The Key field in this query enables a cross-join type function between the two tables when tables don't actually have a linking key.

Comment: as you can see from my answer  - you don't need cross join here (at least as of how question is formulated now) thus no need in artificial key field :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Yes. Nice. Trying it now. Also, we just discovered we were missing part of the query when we copied it over. The query should make more sense now. Also, the error is a different error, which we are correcting above.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You were right about the query not working. We just realized we missed the opening part of the query when we copied it over. It is accurate now and the error BigQuery is throwing is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your recent update in question and comments  - try below

```
WITH Table_L AS (
SELECT 1 AS Row, 'A' AS Hour UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS Row, 'B' AS Hour UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS Row, 'C' AS Hour 
),
Table_R AS (
SELECT 1 AS Row, 10 AS Value UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS Row, 20 AS Value UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS Row, 30 AS Value 
)
SELECT 
  Row, 
  Hour, 
  (SELECT AVG(Value) FROM Table_R) AS AverageOfR,
  1 AS Key
FROM Table_L
```

Above is for testing

the query you should run in "production" is

```
SELECT 
  Row, 
  Hour, 
  (SELECT AVG(Value) FROM Table_R) AS AverageOfR,
  1 AS Key
FROM Table_L
```

In case, if for some reason you are bound to JOIN, use below CROSS JOIN version

```
SELECT 
  Row, 
  Hour, 
  AverageOfR,
  1 AS Key
FROM Table_L
CROSS JOIN ((SELECT AVG(Value) AS AverageOfR FROM Table_R))
```

or below LEFT JOIN version with Key field involved (in case if Key really important for your logic - which somehow I feel is true)

```
SELECT 
  Row, 
  Hour, 
  AverageOfR,
  L.Key AS Key
FROM (SELECT 1 AS Key, Row, Hour FROM Table_L) AS L
LEFT JOIN ((SELECT 1 AS Key, AVG(Value) AS AverageOfR FROM Table_R)) AS R
ON L.Key = R.Key
```

Comment: Just as a clarification - there are over 5 million rows. Does this answer require explicitly selecting each row?

Comment: no, these are just presented as an example for you to test and confirm that it is what you need (ot not). in reality you should just run only select part of it

Comment: This answer worked for us. The different variations are a great addition. (Thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

Your error message suggests that `key` is not a column in `table_L`.  If no, then don't include it in the query.

It looks like you simply want the average of the total from `table_R`.  You can approach this as:

```
SELECT l.*, r.average
FROM test.table_L as l CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT Avg(Total) as average 
      FROM test.table_R
     ) R 
ORDER BY l.hour ASC;
```

Comment: This answer worked for us as did the other answer below as well. (Thanks!)

Comment: @Praxiteles . . . I would consider this the simpler and more direct approach.